# Download GWT plugins for eclipse without using eclipse Instaqll new softeware

Tags: eclipse, gwt, plugins

Is this possible to download GWT plugins for eclipse separately ( without downloading with eclipse directly ) ?
because i need to install it on multiple eclipse on multiple pc and I want to archive it for future needs.

I want to paste it in dropins folder in eclipse later.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip.html

Answer (score 0):

Prepare one eclipse installation the way you like using the standard update sites.

Then you can archive this installation by just copying the eclipse folder and zipping it away somewhere.

To install a new eclipse just take the archive and unzip it on the target system.

With this you have the advantage of still having the automatic updates for the different installations.